# Insert using NHibernate for n:n relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have Orders, Items and OrderItems entities with n:n relationship between Orders and Items table. I am using Fluent Hibernate for mapping, in "Order" entity there is "List" property which has "protective set". I am facing below problem, while inserting.

```
new Order.Items.Add(alreadyexistingitem);
```

Since its already existing item, in the orderitems table, a record needs to be inserted into orderitems table with new orderid and existing item id. But only new order details are inserted in order table not in associative table.

"Inverse" attribute is set for "items" bag in orders entity. So, I need to attach the newly added order while adding item like below but how can i do it as it is the list object with protective set.

```
Orders.Items.Add(alreadyexistingitem, *order = "neworder"*);
```

Below is the mapping:

```
   model.Override<Order>(m =>
   {      

                    m.HasManyToMany(c => c.Items)
                        .Table(Constants.TABLE_PREFIX + "OrderItem")
                        .Inverse()
                        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    });



  model.Override<Item>(m => m.HasManyToMany(c => c.Orders)
                                            .Table(Constants.TABLE_PREFIX + "OrderItem")
                                            .Cascade.None());
```

Comment: Can you show us the mapping you're currently using? That will probably shed more light on the root cause than usage of the mapped object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a preliminary answer, NHibernate is smart enough to know when the same object reference is being used in two places. All you should need is a "HasManyToMany" relationship in the mapping between Order and Item.

Inverse should probably not be used on the orders side. Inverse tells NHibernate that the opposite side of the relationship has the power to define and break the relationship. Orders have items; items don't get to "choose" what order they belong to.

Comment: Thanks Keith, items are getting insert into orderitems table. I am still trying to understand about "inverse" attribute.

Comment: I have same doubt with 1:n relationship, say I have Customer and Order entities. So, order entity has inverse attribute coz order cannot exist without customer like *** model.Override<Order>(m => m.References(c => c.Customers).Inverse().Cascade.None());

Comment: I have researched a bit on this. I think for 1:n relationship, we do it in opposite way i.e., placing inverse on parent, inorder to reduce the number of update statements executed by NHibernate. But for n:n, we need to specify actual relation. Am I right in my understanding. Please comment.